# How to Align the input tag in HTML to bottom right of div?

Tags: html, css

I want to align three input `type=submit` in HTML/CSS to bottom right corner of the screen. Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: You should elaborate a little further. It sounds like you want to fix 3 buttons to the bottom right of your screen rather than align?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1J1WTja Atleast try google search first.

Comment: jsFiddle would be great, or even just the html and css code that you have right now that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>One</button>
      <button>Two</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  min-height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.buttons{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8dr5mv2o/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using position fixed on the input tag.

```css
input[type=submit] {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit">
```